Android CardView white color below card
I have designed a custom component that inherits from cardview. For some reason, it shows a kind of white layout under the card that looks wrong. I have marked it with a red rectangle in the image.

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
android:layout_marginVertical="4dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/ride_sys_color_surface_medium"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/ride_sys_border_radius_container_large"
app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
app:contentPadding="0dp"> ...
 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


Use this:
 app:cardElevation="0dp"

app:cardElevation is used to set the height of the shadow (elevation) around the CardView. It creates a shadow effect for the CardView. When you set it to 0dp, it means you are turning off the shadow.

Could you please be a bit more specific on why this answers the question?

app:cardElevation is used to set the height of the shadow (elevation) around the CardView. It creates a shadow effect for the cardView. when you set it to 0dp. it means you are turning off the shadow.

Please update the answer with this information for completeness. Sorry, forgot to mention this in the initial comment.

oke, i have updated it

Same thing. it didn't work.

My bad. It does work, you just have to apply that property when you call the custom component and not internally in its xml. It does work. Thank you.
